# How does data in a json object get passed in an ajax post?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

This is what the ajax call looks like

```
  $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost/placeadd.php',
      dataType: "json",
      type: "POST",
  data: {
      "location": {
      "lat": -33.8669710,
      "lng": 151.1958750
      },
      "accuracy": 50,
      "name": "Daves Test!",
      "types": ["shoe_store"],
      "language": "en-AU"
      },
      success: function( data){
    console.log(data.status+"<BR>");
      },
      error: function(request, status, error){
        console.log(status+"<BR>");
      }
      })
      })
```

How would I access each element in the php file? For example to access "lat" would it just be $_POST."location"."lat"?

Comment: `$_POST['location']['lat']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/placeadd.php',
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        "location": {"lat": -33.8669710,"lng": 151.1958750},
        "accuracy": 50,
        "name": "Daves Test!",
        "types": ["shoe_store"],
        "language": "en-AU"
    },
    success: function( data){
        console.log(data.status+"<BR>");
    },
    error: function(request, status, error){
        console.log(status+"<BR>");
    }
});
```

In PHP:

```
<?php
    $post = json_decode($_POST);
    $lat = $post['location']['lat'];
    echo $lat;
?>
```